# Have you ever crashed a debugger?

Tags: c++, c, debugging

Recently I was debugging a project and the debugger (GDB 7.1) crashed all of a sudden, because of an endless recursion while trying to print a graph structure. At first I couldn't even imagine that a debugger could crash (a stable version) but it had. So it's really interesting to me, have you ever crashed a debugger?

Comment: Inevitably, just about anyone who has spent several years writing C and/or C++ has encountered a debugger crash.  A debugger is a piece of software, just like any other, and just like any other piece of software, it will have bugs in it.

Comment: Yep, I crashed the QtCreator debugger several times.

Comment: @Justin Ardini : you must be talking about the QtCreator debugger interface, not the actual debugger which would be GDB or something like that?

Comment: @Semen: Debuggers, unlike compilers, are often GUIs at heart, rather than commandline applications.

Comment: If you can't imagine software crashing, then you can't have used much software.

Comment: I'd be more impressed if someone has used GDB *without* crashing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  My coworkers and I were debugging a nasty concurrency bug.

It crashed GDB, so we ran our program under GDB under GDB and eventually found the problem.

It was *so meta* ;)

Answer (score 8):

Yes​​​​​​​​​​​.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  I've crashed DDD fairly frequently, gdb occasionally but not in the last 15 years.